# Docusign Add Locale Information in Docusign Envelope

Tags: docusignapi

Can I pass the Locale information in the XML while sending a document for the signature process?. I am using the REST API version 2.

The default locale is en-US and the embedded signature date is for example '24 DECEMBER 2014' which is added in the . The word 'DECEMBER' needs to be in FRENCH locale when the signer signs the document. This date is added by Docusign in the tag specified. Is there way for me to send the fr-FR locale while sending the document for signature so the embedded information is in the specified locale?

Comment: A quick google taught me that there are account settings dictating what the dates will look like. I'm unfamiliar with the docusign api, but can't you set your preferred locale with the Accept-Language header in the request? I'm hoping the service will honour that.

Comment: The option of setting it at the account level does not work for me because it will be applicable for all the agreements. I tried adding the Accept-Header : fr, verified on fiddler. But the language is still English on the actual document.

Comment: You're just trying to set the recipient's language? Check into *emailNotification* -> *supportedLanguage* in the role

Comment: @Andrew: We are facing a similar issue. Could you please elaborate on the solution you provided? I am not able to understand it clearly.